# Index out of Bounds Exception in Stack Data Structure

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, stack, computer-science

I am writing a program to reverse a word using a stack data structure. The way it's supposed to work is that I input a string, insert each character of the string in a stack object, then I would pop each object out of the stack and print them. The word will be in the reverse order of the original input since that's just how stacks work.

I keep getting an index out of bounds exception; debugging makes me suspect that it has to do with the initial array initialization within the Stack class, but it could also have to do with the push() function.

Here's the entire code:

```
public class Stack      // object to emulate stack data structure
{
private int stackMaxSize;
private char stackArray[];
private int currentSize;

public Stack()    // if initialized without any parameters
{
    this(100);
}

public Stack(int maxSize)      // if initialized with parameter
{
    maxSize = stackMaxSize;
    stackArray = new char[stackMaxSize];
    currentSize = -1;
}

public void push(char c)   //pushes new character into stack
{
    stackArray[++currentSize] = c;
}

public char pop()     //pops character out of stack
{
    return stackArray[currentSize--];
}

public char peek()      // returns character on top of stack
{
    return stackArray[currentSize];
}

public boolean isEmpty()      // returns whether stack is empty or not
{
    return (currentSize < 0);
}
}
```

and here's the main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReverseWord
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Stack wordStack = new Stack(100); // default size is 100

   System.out.print("Enter the word to be reversed: ");
   String word = getString();

    for (byte i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++)    // inserts word into stack char by char
    {
        wordStack.push(word.charAt(i));
    }

    System.out.print(wordStack.pop());


}

static String getString()
{
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     String s = input.nextLine();
     return s;
}

}
```

Thanks a lot!

JLL

Answer (score 3):

In your `Stack(int)` constructor

```
maxSize = stackMaxSize;
```

should be

```
stackMaxSize = maxSize;
```

Comment: That was such a stupid mistake; I'm ashamed of myself. Thanks! I am still getting an out of bounds exception, so something is still wrong with my code.

Comment: You need to loop till `i < word.length()`.

Answer (score 2):

The corrected and working code as follows: (Note that, the main function is written in Stack class for simplicity and corrected code lines are commented)

```
public class Stack // object to emulate stack data structure
{
    private final int  stackMaxSize;
    private final char stackArray[];
    private int        currentSize;

    public Stack() // if initialized without any parameters
    {
        this(100);
    }

    public Stack(final int maxSize) // if initialized with parameter
    {
        this.stackMaxSize = maxSize; /* corrected: assignment reversed */
        this.stackArray = new char[this.stackMaxSize];
        this.currentSize = -1;
    }

    public void push(final char c) // pushes new character into stack
    {
        this.stackArray[++this.currentSize] = c;
    }

    public char pop() // pops character out of stack
    {
        return this.stackArray[this.currentSize--];
    }

    public char peek() // returns character on top of stack
    {
        return this.stackArray[this.currentSize];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() // returns whether stack is empty or not
    {
        return this.currentSize < 0;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Stack wordStack = new Stack(100); // default size is 100

        System.out.print("Enter the word to be reversed: ");
        String word = getString();

        /* corrected: i <= word.length() >> i < word.length() */
        for (byte i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) // inserts word into stack char by char
        {
            wordStack.push(word.charAt(i));
        }

        /* corrected: while loop added to consume the entire stack */
        while (!wordStack.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(wordStack.pop());
        }
    }

    static String getString() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = input.nextLine();
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice that many of the variables are constants. Wouldn't that prevent the value of. .let's say currentSize to be unchangeable?

Answer (score 0):

The problems with the original program was that:
1) For loop should be:

```
  for (byte i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
```

instead of <=        (thanks to ovunccetin)

2) In the constructor of the Stack class

```
maxSize = stackMaxSize;
```

should be:

```
stackMaxSize = maxSize;
```

Thanks to Ravi Thapliyal